# What is the recommended implemementation for OAuth 2 server?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement OAuth 2 server when I found two alternatives:
1- https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server
2- https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize
The 1st one has more than 4.5K downloads with long list of contributors, while the 2nd option is listed under [official OAuth 2 website](https://oauth.net/code/)

Now the question is: What is the best option of above two? Is there a 3rd better option?

Comment: Asking for a library recommendation is not a topic for this site. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Even if it was, you didn't specify your criteria.

Comment: Pls guide me where to open it